# MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE and STR_TO_DATE first conversion error

Tags: php, mysql, file, encoding, format

I have a basic script that takes a file submitted by an html form and adds it to a database:

```
<?php

move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "C:/xampp/files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);   

$con= @new mysqli("127.0.0.1","root","","soilmois");

$file_location = "C:/xampp/files/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

$query =    "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$file_location'
            INTO TABLE testing
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
            (@datetime,column2)
            SET datetime = STR_TO_DATE(@datetime, '%c/%e/%Y %H:%i:%s')";


?>
```

I am having no trouble uploading the file, except the very first entry for the datetime field is always null:

```
0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

I have tried this with multiple text files of the same format and get the same result.

I suspect it has something to do with the character encoding, perhaps the leading character in the file is being included in the first datetime entry.  Any ideas as how to verify the character encoding is the source of the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps try adding the following clause after "FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','": ' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY ","'. Oh, and do your files have header rows? If so, you'll need to add the clause "IGNORE 1 LINES."